# Misshaped blob in caffe

Tags: python, deep-learning, caffe

I'm using the following prototxt:

```
layer {
  name: "pool2"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv5"
  top: "pool2"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_w: 2
    kernel_h: 1
    stride_w: 2
    stride_h: 1
    pad_h: 0
    pad_w: 0
  }
}
```

The blob shape before is 1x64x1x30, and after is 1x64x1x15. Shouldn't it be 1x64x1x14?

From caffe doc:

```
w_o = (w_i + 2*pad_w - kernel_w)/stride_w = (30 - 2)/2 = 14.
```

It makes sense since the pool would be: [0,1] [2,3] [4,5] ... [28,29] which are 14 elements.

Comment: Max pooling with stride 2, kernel size 2 will halve the input. So its correct. You can draw on the paper and verify for yourself.

Comment: Wait haha I miscounted. It is 15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the max pooling layer accepts an input volume of size W1 x H1 x D1 and requires two hyperparameters -- the stride (S) and kernel size (K). It produces an output volume of size W2 x H2 x D2 where we have W2 = (W1 - K)/S + 1,  H2 = (H1 - K)/S + 1, and D2 = D1. Simple computation yields that a kernel size of 2 and stride of 2 halve the input, verifying caffe's network output shape.

Comment: Why do we need to add 1 in the formula?